# Sum various subset of columns to get various subtotal columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Would there be some handy way for summing various subsets of columns in order to get various subtotal columns?

Currently I have a query that calculates data to about 20 distinct fields. I would like to keep the data in these separate fields/columns,
but then I would like to sum various subsets of these fields to get various subtotals. And also the total of all fields to one new field as well.

I can only think of very laborious solution: adding a separate `"sum"`-column for each subset and doing a subset calculation totally from the scratch in each of these columns: `(field1+field2+field2) AS Subset1, (field1+field2+field3+field4) AS subset2, etc. etc. (field1+field2+......+field20) as subsetTotalOfAllFields`. Quite often the next subset builds on top of the previous subset, but as far as I know, at least with this approach, it is not possible to take advantage of previous subset total sum and just add the next column's value to already calculated sum.

Extra problem with the solution above is that in reality there's arithmetic calculation logic inside each original field, so I would not like to repeat those calculations again and again for each subset summing.

Anyone help?

Comment: The sum of subset is like you said `field1+field+field3`, and there isnt a way you can do `Subset1 + field4 as Subset2` unless you do a subquery to get the first result. But that would be very bad performance so just write every subset formula.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just thinking that maybe in this case, it would be better, both in performance wise and code cleanliness, that I would create these combinations in actual code, post-processing the sql results. As far as I understand, I would be forced to repeat the SQL arithmetics inside my fields about 5 times per row - during each subTotal summing.

Comment: Don't worry about that db is very efficient doing that arithmetic.  You can try `explain analyze` to test performance. First try `SELECT f1+f2+f3 as first` then `SELECT f1+f2+f3 as first, f1+f2+f3+f4 as second` and you will see very similar performance